Matrix Multiplication & Addition
I created this small library to perform basic arithmetic on matrices.  I have written the code, and it runs fine. Is there any unexpected behavior or memory leaks? Any room for improvement?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int m;                  // rows
    int n;                  // columns
    int* elements;
} matrix_t;

matrix_t* create_matrix(int m, int n) {
    matrix_t* new_matrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix_t));
    new_matrix->m = m;
    new_matrix->n = n;
    new_matrix->elements = malloc(sizeof(int) * m * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; i++)
        new_matrix->elements[i] = 0;

    return new_matrix;
}

matrix_t* multiply_matrix(matrix_t** first, matrix_t** second) {
    if (first == NULL || second == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((*first)->n != (*second)->m) return NULL;

    matrix_t* product = create_matrix((*first)->m, (*second)->n);

    for (int i = 0; i < (*first)->m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*second)->n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < (*second)->m; k++)
                product->elements[j + i * product->n] +=
                    (*first)->elements[k + i * (*first)->n] * (*second)->elements[j + k * (*second)->n];
        }
    }

    return product;
}

matrix_t* add_matrix(matrix_t** first, matrix_t** second) {
    if (first == NULL || second == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((*first)->m != (*second)->m && (*first)->n != (*second)->n) return NULL;
    matrix_t* sum = create_matrix((*first)->m, (*first)->n);

    for (int i = 0; i < sum->n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sum->m; j++)
            sum->elements[j + i * sum->n] =
                (*first)->elements[j + i * (*first)->n] + (*second)->elements[j + i * (*second)->n];

    return sum;
}

void print_matrix(matrix_t** mat) {
    if (mat == NULL) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < (*mat)->m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*mat)->n; j++)
            printf("%5d", (*mat)->elements[j + i * (*mat)->n]);
        puts("");
    }
}


"basic arithmetic on matrices. "  --> Interesting that OP 's element type is an int.  I'd expect a double.

nabat, Why ultiply_matrix(matrix_t** first, matrix_t** second) instead of ultiply_matrix(matrix_t* first, matrix_t* second)?

Other than what vnp already said in their answer, I'd like to point out a logic error in the code. When checking whether the matrices have the same dimensions in add_matrix, you use the following condition:
(*first)->m != (*second)->m && (*first)->n != (*second)->n

However, there's a problem here. Say you pass a matrix with dimensions m=2, n=3 and another with dimensions m=2, n=5. Since they both have the same m, the first part of the condition will evaluate to false and the && will short circuit to false without ever comparing the ns, which are different. This can be fixed by replacing the && with an ||, as you need at least one of the matrices' dimensions to not match. Hence, the correct condition is:
(*first)->m != (*second)->m || (*first)->n != (*second)->n



create_matrix happily accepts negative arguments. It does not exactly make sense. Semantically m and n (both as arguments and as structure members) should be size_t.
As a side note, prefer calloc to a manual zero-filling.

Why double indirection? Passing first and second as matrix_t * makes the code much more readable.
While we are here, neither add nor multiply mutate the arguments. Qualify them const.



Thanks for the feedback. I've done as you said and made the width and height of size_t. I also used double indirection because I was getting pointer errors but now I don't know what the problem was. I've also made the arguments constant, but I don't understand the calloc part, why does that work?

"Semantically m and n (both as arguments and as structure members) should be size_t" NO! Unsigned types are not better for arithmetic in any way whatsoever, and will in fact introduce an unbelievable amount of new bugs. If you ever have subtraction (which is not unlikely for dimensions) you will have to deal with all the joys of modular arithmetic and its inconsistency with e.g. division, ordering etc.

"create_matrix happily accepts negative arguments" is in itself a pertinent example of why unsigned types does nothing for you: if you  have a bug and pass a negative argument, you now have a matrix with a dimension of about 2^64, which is guaranteed still a bug. In no case does unsigned types automatically fix a bug for you.

@PasserBy You'd get a compile-time warning, wouldn't you?

So the ideal solution would be to check if m and n are less than or equal to zero right?

No. And warnings won't warn about bugs introduced by modular arithmetic (e.g. for(int i = 0; i < m - 2; i++)).

As a side note, prefer calloc to a manual zero-filling. Using calloc() instead of malloc() and then memset() does have one potential performance-impacting quirk - the virtual memory pages might not actually be mapped until they're accessed.  That could cause quite a performance hit during computation if a large array continually causes stalls as each page gets mapped one-by-one the first time it's used.  That might cause a problem because of when the latency appears.

@AndrewHenle Some memory systems use idle time (or another processor) to zero fill blocks of memory - to be on hand for a calloc() like call.

@PasserBy The example you made is not compiled with a well enabled compiler.  Productive programmers learn quickly to employ lots of warnings, such as passing an int to an unsigned argument.

@PasserBy for(int i = 0; i < m - 2; i++)) is fine with size_t as for(size_t i = 0; i + 2 < m; i++)). size_t is the type to use for array sizing and indexing. Yes subtraction can be an issue, yet not hard to avoid - as above. Unsigned types, in general, are better for certain type of math problems. Simply use the right type for the task versus discounting all unsigned uses. Using int has its troubles too including UB due to overflow (unlike unsigned types).

@chux-ReinstateMonica Zero-filling unused physical memory is different from creating the virtual-to-physical mappings a process needs to actually use that memory.  memset() forces that mapping to happen.  Just because calloc() returned a pointer to virtual memory doesn't mean that memory has actually been mapped.  I'd think an OS had better not go around zeroing out memory that's actually mapped to a process...

@chux-ReinstateMonica See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc  Or maybe sift through all of these:  https://www.google.com/search?q=calloc+lazy+mapping+site:stackexchange.com  An application might not want to have to wait for a bunch of lazy-mapped-memory pages to get mapped in the middle of a performance-critical operation.  Calling memset() when allocating the memory is one way to do that.  Imagine a high-volume data stream that can deliver data faster than pages can be mapped.  Ooops - that data now gets lost.  BTDT.

@chux-ReinstateMonica What do you mean by "well enabled compiler"? -Wextra is already quite aggressive in warnings. The example loop is precisely the type of gotchas that unsigned types do to you. How is that transformation the obviously correct one? Why would you subject yourself to such counter-intuitive situations for no reason? You claim that unsigned types are better for certain math problems, please give me an example, because I can't think of one. I can give you several more reasons why array indexing should be signed, but that is probably too much for comments.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Actually, I can think of one, which is division by powers of 2, which might happen with matrix dimensions. The solution is unfortunately to explicitly write right shift for signed integers. However, I argue that this is much less of a problem because it's not a bug, it's a pessimization.

This code is completely missing the error-handling for when malloc() returns a null pointer.  Which makes the entire program's behaviour undefined on any occasion we run out of storage.

This is suspect:

matrix_t* multiply_matrix(matrix_t** first, matrix_t** second) {
    if (first == NULL || second == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((*first)->n != (*second)->m) return NULL;


We don't check *first or *second are not null before dereferencing them.  Mind you, it's unclear why we're passing pointer to pointer here.

I don't think these functions have any business modifying the matrices passed as arguments.  So they should be matrix_t const* const* to express (and enforce) that.

The calculation of matrix->elements[column + row * matrix->n] is repeated several times; I think it would be clearer as a small inlinable function (or perhaps a pair of functions for const-correct read and write).

If we're always going to dynamically allocate matrix_t objects, then perhaps we should use a flexible array member for elements rather than another pointer indirection.
